# div dentro de otro ocupar 100% del ancho del contenedor y position absolute

Tags: css

hola chicos estoy seguro que esta pregunta es facil tengo 2 divs uno tiene 450px de ancho y dentro de ese tengo otro div que quiero que ocupe el 100% de ancho y que tenga un position absolute , pero al colocarle position absolute se sale del contenedor aqui mi codigo

```css
.padre{
 
 width: 200px;
 height: 400px;
 background-color:green;

}
.hijo{
 
 width: 100%;
 height:200px;
 background-color: grey;
 position:absolute;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="padre">
   
<div class="hijo">

</div>     
  
</div>
```

como veran el div hijo se sale del contenedor lo que yo nececito es que siempre me ocupe el mismo ancho del div padre sin importar que espero que puedan ayudarme gracias !

Comment: ¿Si omites la posición absoluta aún no obtendrías el resultado deseado?

Comment: noup, nececito que tenga una position absoluta!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes agregarle `position: relative` al div padre asi:

```css
.padre{
 
 width: 200px;
 height: 400px;
 background-color:green;
 position: relative;

}
.hijo{
 
 width: 100%;
 height:200px;
 background-color: grey;
 position:absolute;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="padre">
   
<div class="hijo">

</div>     
  
</div>
```

Comment: gracias por la ayuda  amigo!!

Comment: De nada @chosen